# Umbraco and Omeka integration?

Tags: content-management-system, integration, umbraco

I've been asked to integrate Omeka CMS with umbraco CMS in the same website/project. Do you know if this is possible and if its possible where can I start?

I already "googled it" but I don't find any useful information.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify how they are to be integrated. Will both be serving content to the same website? What have you been asked to achieve?

Comment: Hello Digbyswift. Basically the current website is built with umbraco and now they want to integrate a new functionality like a bibliogrpahical tool...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're thinking of integrating a new CMS into a website that is already being controlled using Umbraco, purely for the creating new functionality, I would seriously suggest creating the new functionality in Umbraco itself.

Whilst it is probably possible, it would be a developmental nightmare in the future, difficult to maintain (by the developers *and* administrators), and deployments would also be a pain. It just doesn't make sense to mix the two technologies either (i.e. .NET and PHP) if Umbraco is almost certainly capable of providing the functionality you require.

Comment: Hey Digbyswift... Thats exactly what I thought. However the people that are asking me this don't understand this kind of things. To get things wrost I never worked with Omeka so it would be even more painful. Well thanks for your feedback and I'll try to explain this... If they dont understand... wish me luck!

Comment: If the client is asking for the new CMS, explain that it would be more expensive in the short term *and* long term to integrate the CMS. More dev time required, more deployment time required, more complicated server infrastructure, more involved administration for them too. If their intention is to ultimately move to Omeka (someone may have made an executive decision), the explain that it maybe more finanically viable to rebuild from scratch in the new CMS. Although we devs do not deal with the financial ramifications, the client will be lead primarily by budget, so explain in these terms.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense and that's probably what I'll (have to) do. Just wanted to check that it was really a bad idea and that integration is not something worth of doing.